# What is wrong with this c++ code?

Tags: c++

As you can see I am new to C++, but I can't understand why `y = new Person()` in function `foo` is wrong. Thanks for your help.

I get the this error:

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘y = (((Person*)operator new(32u)),
>   (, ))’

### UPDATE:

I will accept the answer with the most upvotes by tonight or the one that is more convincing.

**The argument between me and my friend is wether the function foo can change the object and propagate the change outside the function like when doing `y = Person()`, then also `brother` will change or will it remain intact?**
.

### CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 class Person {
   public:  
    int age;
    char name[25];

    Person() {
            age = 0;

    }
};

void foo(Person &y)
{
    y = new Person();
}

int main()
{
    Person *brother = new Person();
    brother->age = 20;

    cout << "age = " << brother->age << endl;
    foo(*brother);
    cout << "age = " << brother->age << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to understand the difference between a *reference* and a *pointer* - then it will all become clear.. :)

Comment: What is `foo` supposed to do? It appears that it's intended to be passed a person, then create a new person and do nothing with it, ignoring the person it was passed and leaving the new person leaked.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This is a dare between me and my friend about passing references in parameter so i created an example to see who's right :)

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong with it in a useful way without knowing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Nim I see your point. thanks

Comment: @AdelBoutros what is the purpose of this code and your question? What is the exact statement that you and your friend disagree on?

Comment: @AdelBoutros: Don't accept answers based on upvotes. Accept the one that is right in your opinion. Be honest :)

Comment: @phresnel I asked a question because I don't know the answer, So how can I be honest? When you upvote, it means it is correct.

Comment: @Dialecticus I have included in the update what the argument between me and my friend is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void foo(Person &y)
{
    y = new Person();
}
```

`y` is a reference, not a pointer. To reassign to `y`, you'd use

```
y = Person();
```

but if you really want to allocate a new person, you'd use

```
void foo(Person* &y) // reference to pointer to Person
```

With a reference, you basically say that you modify the value at the calling site.

Note that your current code leak. If you have a bare pointer that you want to manage yourself, you have to delete it first:

```
void foo (Person*& y)
{
    delete y;
    y = new Person;
}
```

But as you see, the code is already becoming messy without knowing your target. It might be more appropriate to `delete` at the calling site, or to not allocate `y` at all before calling `foo(...)`.

Also note that using `foo (Person* y)` instead would not solve the issue of `new`ing at the calling site:

```
void foo (Person *y) 
{
    y = new Person();
}
```

This of course compiles, but modifies only `foo`'s own `y` variable. The caller will have an unchanged pointer.

Note that you'd better use value types or smart pointers, as it is non-trivial to write exception safe code that manually manages memory.

Answer (score 7):

You probably come from a language were objects can only be created with new. In C++, this is not the case. And unless you really need it, you should not use new. Just create it as a normal variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    unsigned age;
    std::string name;
    Person(unsigned age, std::string name)
        : age(age)
        , name(std::move(name)) // move is C++11
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Person brother(8, "Tim John");
    std::cout << "age = " << brother.age << '\n';
    // Edit regarding the question in the comments:
    brother = Person(16, "John Tim");
    std::cout << "age = " << brother.age << '\n';
}
```

Your problem with the code above is that new returns a Pointer, and you are trying to assign a pointer to a Person, which obviously can't work.

Comment: @cooky451: I believe that the use of `std::move` here is unnecessary, because the parameter is already a temporary (pass-by-copy). I am not so aware of move semantics though... Are you sure it is ?

Comment: @Matthieu `name` is an lvalue. It won't be moved automatically.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: No, the function argument isn't a temporary; its lifetime covers the whole of the constructor and so without `std::move` it would be copied (in this case, optimisation would probably give the same result as a move, but that's not guaranteed).

Comment: Btw, in your code you have opted out the function foo, why? For me it's the core of what I am trying to do.

Comment: he is asking for a compile error not the good practice for doing the things in c++..i think your answer is completely outside the context

Comment: @AdelBoutros: The function body would be `y = Person();`, copy-assigning a default-constructed temporary to the object referred to by the argument. The temporary is destroyed automatically at the end of the line. Then you call it as `foo(brother);`.

Comment: I have included in the update what the argument between me and my friend is

Comment: @riskio The compile error is explained in 1 sentence, but that is not very helpful at all since he obiously didn't know that objects can be constructed without new.

Comment: @cooky451 You haven't answered my question yet

Comment: @AdelBoutros Yes, sorry. I left out foo() because it is kind of senseless when you already have the possibility of copy/move construction. Just use my_person = Person(75, "My Grandma"); - and you're done. No new / delete needed here at all.

Answer (score 2):

In function foo the line should be

```
y = Person();
```

`y` is not a pointer.

EDIT: actually, this is the wrong answer (even though you're currently accepted it from Jon). You are not supposed to mix heap and stack, and cause memory leaks like that. The right way to do it is to change members of the object directly. Assignment operator (operator=) will change the members of the object. Because the question is not about mixing heap and stack, but about changing object here's the code that better explains the problem. Note that there's no `new` here to complicate the issue.

```
void foo(Person &y)
{
    y = Person();
}

int main()
{
    Person brother;
    brother.age = 20;

    ...
    foo(brother);
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

After `y = Person()` the `brother` object will be changed because `y` **is** `brother` and assignment operator changes the members of the object.

Comment: So after exiting the function foo and in the main, brother.age will be 0 or 20 ?

Comment: It will be zero. If they were pointers then assignment would change only the pointer, but on objects (which is your case) it changes the members of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Never confuse yourself with the `&` and `*` operators when dealing with pointer operations.
'&' is used in different context.
`&`, when used in a function's formal parameters is a reference parameter , this operator passes a variable by reference(by its address).However the variable `y` still acts like a normal variable.
So this block of code..

```
void foo(Person &y) 
{ 
y = new Person(); 
}
```

would not work as `new Person()` is parsing a pointer to a variable.
For example,

```
int * intp = new int;
int variable = intp;
```

this is the type of thing that's happening here.A reference parameter acts like a variable but actually has direct access to the variable due to the fact that it's a call by referance operation. 
The correct way to write this function will look like this

```
 void foo(Person ** y) 
{ 
*y = new Person(); 
}
```

That is if you're trying to initialize a class pointer via a function.
As **cooky** said this is a misconception people make in c++ whom program in languages that require the `new` keywork in order to create an object/variable.
**SOURCES** 
http://fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/functions/refparams.html

Comment: I assume you mean this:

void foo(Person **y) 
{ 
    *y = new Person(); 
}

Comment: Oh yes my mistake , sorry it was very late when i wrote this post.Thanks Larry.

Answer (score 1):

you are tryng to call the "new" operator on a reference. while the "new" is used only with pointers.
pass to `void foo( )` function

```
 Person*
```

instead of

```
Person&
```

**A little explanation :**

The right way to pass a parameter depends on what you have to do!!

If you want to do side effects to the object passed to the function the right way is to declare :

```
void foo(Person& person)
```

the object person can be modified..
if you don t waant to do side effects to the object you have to declare the object 'const':

```
void foo(const Person& person)
```

the const means  you cannot modify the object inside your method even if you are passing a reference..

then you can pass a pointer:

```
void foo(Person* person)
```

here you can modify the object that "person" is pointing at, but you have a copy of the original pointer.

last way to pass parameters is :

```
void foo(Person*& person)
```

here you have an alias of the original pointer. alias means "the same pointer with a different name"